# Angular 4.3 HttpClient put doesn't fire

Tags: angular, request, httpclient, put

I've got this httpclient request in an angular 4.3 service:

```
updateTermin(termin: Termin){
  let url = '${this.termineUrl}/${termin.id}';
  this.http
  .put(url, termin, {headers: this.headers})
}
```

it only gets fired if i append a .subscribe() like this:

```
updateTermin(termin: Termin){
  let url = '${this.termineUrl}/${termin.id}';
  this.http
  .put(url, termin, {headers: this.headers})
  .subscribe()
}
```

The other request (delete or post) work without append .subscribe(). Why?

Comment: No, they don't. You need to subscribe for a HTTP request to be sent, whatever the method is.

Comment: It cant be, you need subscribe

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `HttpClient` request methods (all of them) return an Observable: basically it's a chain of commands waiting to be executed.  Nothing happens until you call `subscribe()` on that chain. So `this.http.put(...)` only prepares the commands for you.

If you're coming from an environment that uses promises, this will seem counter-intuitive because a promise executes as soon as it comes alive. Observables are different. Check out this [short intro on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sol2uLolmUM)

Comment: spot on, never knew about waiting on the call to subscribe!

Comment: Almost half day digging this issue.. Thanks @BeetleJuice for the answer.